# How to Implement Recurring Order Remainder Notification for Customer?

Tags: magento-1.9, customer, email-reminders, notification

How can I create module like monthly regular customer received notification like, your monthly order is ready, get it. How can I do this for my customer.

Comment: did you tried anything?

Comment: actually i did like, manually send mail to customer,, i need inside the magento just remind to customer this is the time to get your monthly order.

Comment: You can setup cron job which collect all the customers whose has monthly order and then fire the notification.

Comment: Could you pls explain briefly about that

Comment: Please put the code that you used to send manully.

Answer (score 0):

You can use crones in Magento.
Something more about it :
http://docs.magento.com/m1/ce/user_guide/system-operations/cron.html

and tutorial:
http://inchoo.net/magento/creating-cron-script-in-magento/

In cron - Model class You have to write code sending email for your customers.
Oh important is how to set crons works like You want (eg once for motnh):
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CronHowto
https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-do-i-add-jobs-to-cron-under-linux-or-unix-oses/

You can also use crone generator online:
http://www.cronmaker.com/
http://crontab-generator.org/

There is AOE Scheduler for manage crons for Magento 1
https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/aoe-scheduler.html